# How to add the group of cells with the same structure in RDLC report?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have an RDLC report and want to add the group of cells with the same structure as in red rectangle next to the right?

I can easily add the whole column, but third, fourth and fifth rows don't contain 2 cells. There's only one empty cell.

Please, take a look at the screen shot attached.[image]

Comment: What do you mean does not contain 2 cells ? Can you make clear what output do you expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two columns to the right, and then merge two cells in the "header" rows by clicking on the first cell, pressing Shift key and then selecting the second cell. "Merge" option will be available on right-click for those two cells then as long as you are still holding Shift key.